# C Preprocessing Token concatenation

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

How do I use C preprocess to automatically generate the following code pattern (accessor)?

```
// Immutable accessor.
const auto& member1 () const {
  return _member1;  // private class member
}

// Mutable accessor.
auto& member1() {  
  return _member1;  // private class member
}
```

I tried the following but it didn't work...

```
#define EXPAND_ACCESSOR(item) constexpr const auto& ##item() const { return _##item; } \
                              constexpr auto& ##item() { return _##item; }


EXPAND_ACCESSOR(member1)  // didn't work
```

Comment: You need \ ( with no Whitespace after )  at the end of each continued line.

Comment: I did. The compiler complains about  error: pasting "&" and "member1" does not give a valid preprocessing token
 #define EXPAND_ACCESSOR(item) constexpr const auto& ##item() const { return _##item; }\

Comment: #define does not work with spaces, unless inside strings, this is why DEFINE _CONSTNAT and so on used. Use **typedef** last word is replaced with everything before , including multilines. Ends with ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a macro to accomplish what you are trying. Your macro needs a few tweaks. (I am using three lines to help with the answer)

You have:

```
#define EXPAND_ACCESSOR(item) \
   constexpr const auto& ##item() const { return _##item; } \
   constexpr auto& ##item() { return _##item; }
```

Problems with the macro:

```
   constexpr const auto& ##item() const { return _##item; } \
                         ^^ Not appropriate.
```

I get the following error from g++:

```
error: pasting "&" and "member1" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

You need to use just:

```
#define EXPAND_ACCESSOR(item) \
   constexpr const auto& item() const { return _##item; } \
   constexpr auto& item() { return _##item; }
```

That fixes the proprocessor errors but it leads to errors related to return type. When you have `auto` in the return type, you'll need to using a trailing return type.

Use of `constexpr` with the non-`const` member function is not appropriate. When a member function is qualified with `constexpr`, it is assumed to be `const` member function. Hence, you need to remove the `constexpr` from that function.

Here's a fixed up macro that should work:

```
#define EXPAND_ACCESSOR(item) \
   constexpr const decltype( _ ## item) & item() const { return _ ## item; } \
   decltype( _ ## item) & item() { return _ ## item; }
```

Comment: Hi Sahu, Thank you. This is exactly what I want. Would you please help me again with the EXPAND_MUTATOR(item) which I intended to generate set_item(const decltype(item)& val) { _item = val; } ?  I tried #define EXPAND_MUTATOR(item)  void set_item(const decltype(_##item)& val) { _##item = val; } but it fail to compile.

Comment: @Jes, you need to use `set_ ## item` to  create `set_member1`. The macro needs to defined as `#define EXPAND_MUTATOR(item) void set_##item(const decltype(_##item)& val) { _##item = val; }`

Answer (score -2):

**typedef** syntax:

```
typedef struct Books {
char title[50];
char author[50];
char subject[100];
int book_id;
 } Book;
```

'Book' is replaced with the whole struct definition before.  ; are valid within {}.

Comment: What has this answer to do with the question?